# Setting two rowsources in same procedure is terrible slow - Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, odbc

I have two Listboxes which are filled via vba on a click event. The table 'Project' is a odbc datasource with 250 records.

```
List1.RowSource = "SELECT Name FROM Project WHERE ProjectID = " & ProjectID.Caption & " AND Year = " & ActualYear.Caption & " ORDER BY Name"

List2.RowSource = "SELECT ProjectShare FROM Project WHERE ProjectID = " & ProjectID.Caption & " AND Year = " & ActualYear.Caption & " ORDER BY Name"
```

So far so good. But when I run this code, it takes everytime up to 30sec to complete. I thought, okay it's because of odbc and so on. But when I run only one line of this code (no matter which), it is fast as lightning (0,1sec).

How can it be, that one query takes 0,1sec and two querys 30sec? May I could make a break between these two lines? Btw. without odbc everything works like a charm, no matter how many lines

Comment: Hard to tell. You might have a locking problem there. You could bind both lists to the same recordset (pull in both _Name_ and _ProjectShare_), and hide the 2nd column in the first list, and the first column in the second list. That might improve speed considerably. I could share the code as an answer, if you're interested.

Comment: You could try a DoEvents between the two lines. But Erik's suggestion is far more elegant, and less overhead.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Using the same SQL string two times hasn't changed anything. Is there an other way to bind them to the same recordset?

Comment: Yes, I'll just share the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind both listboxes to the same recordset by manually creating the recordset. This allows Access to only query the table once instead of twice at the same time, avoiding any locking conflicts, and tends to avoid other problems as well.

This also allows you to use parameters, fixing any errors introduced by string concatenation.

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "SELECT Name, ProjectShare FROM Project WHERE ProjectID = p1 AND Year = p2 ORDER BY Name")
    .Parameters(0).Value= ProjectID.Caption
    .Parameters(1).Value = ActualYear.Caption
    Set rs = .OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot) 'Snapshot because it won't be updated
End With
Set list1.Recordset = rs
Set list2.Recordset = rs
```

Note that I have had errors occur when an object bound to a recordset with parameters was requeried, so you might want to use string concatenation if that's happening.